# Element not Interactable Error when trying to automate a process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to send a value and click on the button to retrieve certain pdfs but I am getting an error that element is not interactable. I tried using different selectors but I am getting the same error.
Below is my code:

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options=Options()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "D:\Trvael_Test_Script\GSTInvoiceDownloads"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
s=Service('C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)
driver.get("link")

time.sleep(10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GST"]/span[1]'))).click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID,'ifgstdownloadnFrame'))

time.sleep(5)


driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txtpnr"]').send_keys('pnr')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()```

Can anyone please let me know how to make the element interactable?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a character sequence to the ***PNR*** field you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtpnr").send_keys("AGQR8U")
  ```

---

Ideally to send the text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://book.spicejet.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='GST Invoice']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#GSTInvoicePopUP iframe#ifgstdownloadnFrame")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtpnr"))).send_keys("AGQR8U")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spicejet_GST]

Comment: I am able to click on GST Invoice, but I am unable to send the pnr value to the popup that comes after that. I need to send PNR value to that box which give element not interactable error.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.